# Inner com 3 tabelas PHP/SQL

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou com 3 tabelas e quero comparar o valor delas, eu consigo fazer com 2 usando o `JOIN` mas quando coloco `JOIN` na terceira o [php](/questions/tagged/php) não dá certo.

Código em PHP:

```
$agora = "select * from usuario u 
          join dia_usuario du 
          on u.usuario_id = du.id_diarista 
          join diarista d 
          on d.id = ud.id_diarista";
$sim = mys[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]qli_query($conn,$agora);
while ($row_usuario2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sim)) {
    $ola2 = $row_usuario2['nome'];
}
```

Tabela usuario

[image: Tabela Usuario]

Tabela dia_usuario

[image: Tabela dia_usuario]

Tabela diarista

[image: Tabela Diarista]

Retorno da consulta

[image: retorno da consulta]

Comment: qual erro o php mostra?

Comment: @Enerson Silva coloca a resposta do Anderson como correta pf.

Comment: Simples, seu problema está na segunda tabela, você só tem o id_diarista 3 e 5 então ele só trás o usuário emerson que tem o usuario_id igual a 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu erro está no segundo igual, você colocou "ud" e não "du"

```
$agora = "select * from usuario u 
          inner join dia_usuario du 
          on u.usuario_id = du.id_diarista 
          inner join diarista d 
          on d.id = du.id_diarista";
$sim = mysqli_query($conn,$agora);
while ($row_usuario2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sim)) {
    $ola2 = $row_usuario2['nome'];
}
```

=========

Você só encontra o usuário enerson por causa do seguinte...

Você está pegando todos os dados de usuário de diferentes tabelas onde o id do usuário seja igual ao id diarista e o id da tabela diarista(Não o id_diarista) seja igual ao o id_diarista...

Sendo assim o usuário enerson tem o id 3 que é igual ao id_diarista 3 que é igual ao id da tabela diarista que também é 3... O outro valor é 5 e não há nenhum usuário com o id 5 no momento, Deu para sacar?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82805/discussion-on-answer-by-anderson-henrique-inner-com-3-tabelas-php-sql)

Answer (score 0):

O que está acontecendo é o fato de você estar restringido sua busca pelo conteúdo das tabelas relacionadas.

O que isso significa?

O seu join restringe os retornos do conjunto final filtrando os resultados que estão nos conjuntos relacionados ao conjunto principal.

Se você quer trazer os dados que estão presentes na tabela principal e fazer a coalescência do que não existe nas tabelas B e C da sua busca, você deve usar o left join.

no caso, sua query ficaria parecida com isso:

```
select 
* 
from usuario u 
left join dia_usuario du 
  on u.usuario_id = du.id 
left join diarista d 
  on d.id = du.id;
```

Não quero parecer grosseiro nem pretensioso, mas vejo que você parece estar iniciando nos estudos sobre banco de dados, pude perceber que sua modelagem ainda não reflete bem a realidade do que você quer com sua aplicação.

Sugiro estudar um pouco mais como funcionam os joins nas consultas, para isso segue abaixo um artigo pequeno porém interessante:

http://dan-scientia.blogspot.com/2012/10/teoria-dos-conjuntos-em-juncoes-sql.html

Boa sorte aí na sua aplicação, e espero que minha contribuição seja útil.

Comment: me ajudou, não foi grosseiro sou iniciante em banco de dados.

Comment: Show de bola Enerson Silva. Bons estudos!